# A strange c++ code phenomenon

Tags: c++, fstream

Look at these two programs:

#1:

```
int main(){
    ulong num = 100;
    float *pFArr = new float[num];
    if(!pFArr)return 0;

    for(ulong i=0; i<num; i++)
        pFArr[i] = 22.4f*(float)i - 11.4f;

    ofstream file("fArr.dat");
    if(!file){delete []pFArr; return 0;}
    if(!file.write((char*)&num,sizeof(num))){file.close(); delete []pFArr; return 0;}
    if(!file.write((char*)pFArr,num*sizeof(float))){file.close(); delete []pFArr; return 0;}
    file.close();

    delete []pFArr;
}
```

#2:

```
int main(){
    ulong num = 100;
    float *pFArr = new float[num];
    if(!pFArr)return 0;

    for(ulong i=0; i<num; i++)
        pFArr[i] = 53.2f*(float)i - 22.5f;


    ofstream file("fArr.dat");
    if(!file){delete []pFArr; return 0;}
    if(!file.write((char*)&num,sizeof(num))){file.close(); delete []pFArr; return 0;}
    if(!file.write((char*)pFArr,num*sizeof(float))){file.close(); delete []pFArr; return 0;}
    file.close();

    delete []pFArr;
}
```

The single code difference between the two is the assignment of the array elements. However, the first program saves a 404 bytes file (4 bytes for "num" and 100*4 bytes for the elements), while the second one saves a 405 bytes file!!

When I read the files using this code:

```
int main(){
    ulong num = 0;
    float *pFArr = null;

    ifstream file("fArr.dat");
    if(!file)return 0;

    if(!file.read((char*)&num,sizeof(num))){file.close(); return 0;}

    pFArr = new float[num];
    if(!pFArr){file.close(); return 0;}
    for(ulong i=0; i<num; i++)
        pFArr[i] = 0;
    if(!file.read((char*)pFArr,num*sizeof(float))){delete []pFArr; file.close(); return 0;}

    for(ulong i=0; i<num; i++)
        cout<<pFArr[i]<<"\n";

    delete []pFArr;
    file.close();
}
```

the 404 file is read successfully.
For the 405 file, the second "file.read" call fails. When I ignore the failure and continue displaying the array elements, I see that elements from 0 to 46 were assigned the right values, the "pFArr[47]" element has a strange value (x.xxxxxe-0xx), and the rest of the array were not assigned.
Can someone explain why this is happening??
Another issue: Avast! is always blocking the reading program, what's wrong with the code?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is there a reason you're not opening the files in binary mode?

Comment: @RetiredNinja. I bet theres an accidental \n in there among those floats that gets converted to \r\n

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware of that. Now I opened it in binary mode and the problem's gone, but Avast! is still blocking the program!!

Comment: Avast! is very aggressive.  You can exclude directories from the shields in the settings->antivirus section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good chance that, because you're opening it in the default text mode, there are some translations going on under the covers. That gels with the fact that this appears to be a data-related problem.

For example, Windows may convert a `\n` byte to a `\r\n` sequence. A good idea would be to do a hex dump of the file to see if it has this sequence in it.

If it does, ensure you open it in binary mode instead:

```
ofstream file("fArr.dat", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
```

In fact, you probably want to do that anyway just to avoid potential problems in future (to *all* code that reads/writes binary information, such as your reader program as well).

Comment: Yes I did that and it worked now, but Avast! is still blocking the program, can you see any other problem with the code?

Comment: No, it seems to work okay, and I can't spot any obvious things like buffer overflows or carrying on after errors. I _would_ open the file in binary mode as well just in case. Other than that, it may just be Avast giving a false positive virus detection on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you read out the number, it isn't converted correctly into an unsigned long. Im pretty sure this is the problem because you have an issue at the array index 47 and 48 is in the ASCII table a 0. You should convert the chars into ulong.